# Eloquent ( Where from other table? )

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I have this working Query, Which gets all Projects, With their Countries, And all the continents for the countries

```
$projects = Project::with('country.continent')->get();
```

Now i'm trying to do a Where, to only get the results from a specific continent with the following query

```
$projects = Project::where('continent.name', $sub)->with('country.continent')->get();
```

But this is failing, It's looking for 'continent.name' in the Projects table, but it's in the nested table

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

From the [Laravel docs](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#eager-loading):

> Eager Load Constraints
>
> Sometimes you may wish to eager load a relationship, but also specify
>   a condition for the eager load. Here's an example:
>
> ```
> $users = User::with(array('posts' => function($query) 
> {
>     $query->where('title', 'like', '%first%'); 
> }))->get();
> ```
>
> In this example, we're eager loading the user's posts, but only if the
>   post's title column contains the word "first".

So [**warning: untested code**]

```
$projects = Project::with(array('country.continent') => function($query) use ($sub){
    $query->where('name',$sub);}))->get();
}
```

might do it.